# Asynchronous tasks in a serverless environment

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently working on an Angular project in which our users would upload a picture to our back-end via API Gateway and lambda functions. Our back-end (an EC2 instance, for example) will then transform the picture and save it in an S3 bucket ready to be displayed to the user. This operation might take up to 30 seconds.

I was wondering what is the "state of the art" **serverless** way of having the front-end wait for the back-end to complete the operation and "immediately" show it to the end-user. In essence, how do I "subscribe" and wait for the server to complete the operation via API Gateway and lambda functions?

I have thought of the following options but none of them appears to be used in this context:

1) Have the front-end call regularly (e.g. every second) the API checking for the specific picture id in the S3 bucket via a lambda function (i.e.: GET /obtain-picture/{id} and wait until a 200 is received and ignore the 404 responses.

2) Have the back-end push a message "complete for id {id}" to an SQS queue. Then, the front-end would pull regularly (e.g. every second) the SQS queue (via a lambda function that would only extract the appropriate information) and check if the pulled message contains the relevant ID. Again, I am not very sure on how scalable this would be.

3) Use a "push-like" service such as SNS and wait for the server to push a message, but I am unsure whether this is even feasible based on the very little resources found.

4) I have read about "asynchronous" lambda calls, but I am unsure on how this would work and how the server could put a lambda function "on-hold" meaning I wouldn't be billed for it. Would [THIS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html) be a solution?

Is there a better way to have the website "wait" until the server "notifies" it that it has completed its processing? In this sense, I am mostly thinking about websites where we would upload a profile picture (LinkedIn), and after loading (and certainly doing a lot of processing), the Website shows the formatted profile picture.

Any relevant resources or tips would be very much appreciated, even if not very detailed

N.B: I am aware of the possibility to "subscribe" and wait for a server response via Angular, but I am not sure how "subscribing" to a lambda function (via API Gateway) stop it from running for too long (I'd like to avoid "unoptimized" billing).

Thank you very much in advance and apologies in case this question is a duplicate.

Comment: I found this article useful: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-backend-requests-and-frontend-notifications-in-serverless-web-apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that implementing a websocket API is the cleanest approach to have a front-end wait for something in the back to be completed.

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html).